# Using regexp_replace string

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I am trying to use oracle REGEXP_REPLACE function to remove repeated chars.

The string looks like the following:

```
("ABC","DEF,,,,",,,"111",,,"HI")
```

The output should be:

```
("ABC","DEF,,,,","111","HI")
```

To achieve this, i tried the following code

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(("ABC","DEF,,,,",,,"111",,,"HI")','[,]{2,}','(,))
FROM DUAL;
```

This is removing the comma inside doble quotes. Can someone tell me how to remove duplicate comma not in the double quotes?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal?  Perhaps there's a better way to get to the end result.  i.e. This looks like you are getting data from a spreadsheet where there are NULL columns (the consecutive commas).  If you are ending up loading this into a table via sqlldr, this can be handled in the control file if you only care about fields 1,2,5 and 8.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to remove repeated comma or some special chars which is present more than 2 times outside of double quotes in the input string. This is i am getting from UI. Say for another example. The input string will be "AAAAA123!!!!","BBB",!!!!!,"CAAD",!!!). The output will be "AAAAA123!!!!","BBB",!,"CADD",!). i want to achieve this using regexp_replace string. Pl.let me know is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are the repeating characters being introduced?  The UI or the user? Program that extracts data from a database under the UI? What do you do with the data once cleaned up? Please share the bigger picture, it may help to understand the big picture in order to offer better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LISTAGG('"'||test||'"', ',')
     WITHIN GROUP (order by r) "t" from
(select rownum r ,regexp_substr(q'"ABC","DEF,,,,",,,"111",,,"HI"','[^"]+', 1, level) test from dual
connect by regexp_substr(q'"ABC","DEF,,,,",,,"111",,,"HI"', '[^"]+', 1, level) is not null)
where regexp_count( test, ',' ) != LENGTH(test)
```

this works.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try that and also is there any way to directly use regexp replace function to achieve the above criteria. Thanks in advance.